# How do I run a ruby script from a webpage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a total newb when it comes to programming and I'm trying to connect to a rest API with ruby on rails since it seemed like a good option to pick.

Before I try to connect to the API i'm just trying to figure out how to run a script from a webpage but it just tries to save the .rb file when I navigate to it in a browser. The code i have in the file is:

```
puts "hello world"
```

I uploaded the .rb file to my web server and went to the URL and it just tries to save the file. Sorry for the stupid question but I can't figure out how to do it!

Comment: Are you trying to run your Ruby script on the web page?

Comment: a) i can't think of a situation where rails would do what you're expecting with a file with that content b) There is SO much knowledge you're lacking that one can't really answer this question in a way that gets you what you want without writing a small book. Please check out any of the many getting started with rails books.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, to run off simple commands like that, you can run ruby scripts via the terminal:

```
ruby /path/to/ruby/script.rb
```

Otherwise, if you insist on using a webserver for such purpose (or, if your use-case requires so), you should look at simple ruby-based web servers/frameworks like [rack](https://github.com/rack/rack), [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com), etc.

Particularly, in rack, you can save the following file (lets, say as: hello.rb):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rack'

def application(env)
   [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/html"}, "Hello world."]
end

Rack::Handler::Mongrel.run method(:application), :Port => 9292
```

Then, you can run the above file using terminal:

```
ruby /path/to/hello.rb
```

And, this will create a local web server with port 9292, and you can open the above page at: `http://127.0.0.1:9292/`, and the page will say: `Hello world.`

Comment: Ok cool thanks. I did use the terminal to do hello world but I figured I might as well learn now how to actually make the script live and viewable instead of being console only

Answer (score 2):

You need an app server in order to serve a web page. Look at sinatra, rails and rack.

http://m.onkey.org/ruby-on-rack-1-hello-rack

Answer (score 2):

A classic web server (like Apache, nginx, Tomcat, etc.) do exactly what you are describing, as well as do many other functions. To run ruby scripts, you'll need a Ruby application server, and the web server needs to reverse-proxy requests to that server. Definitely take a some tutorials around Rails and you'll see tons of examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a Ruby script on the client-side (instead of on a server), you can use a Ruby-to-JavaScript compiler such as [Opal](http://opalrb.com/) or [ruby2js](https://github.com/rubys/ruby2js), or a Ruby-to-WebAssembly compiler such as [run.rb](https://runrb.io/).

For example, Opal translates `puts "hello world"` into

```
/* Generated by Opal 0.11.0 */
(function(Opal) {
  var self = Opal.top, $nesting = [], nil = Opal.nil, $breaker = Opal.breaker, $slice = Opal.slice;

  Opal.add_stubs(['$puts']);
  return self.$puts("hello world")
})(Opal);
```